# How to use R in HPC SSH frontend?

Tags: r, linux, ssh, directory

I used to use R in RStudio which make it easer to handle.
As I got a bigger data I got access to a HPC of the university through SSH interface (MobaXterm) which could be done using terminal as well.
My problem is my inability to access to the administration, which prevent me from installing packages. And I'm pretty sure that I need to change one of the libraries directory that I don't have access to it.

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/home/UserIsMe/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2"
[2] "/cm/shared/apps/R/4.2.1/lib64/R/library"
```

Is there any way to change the second directory to mine (like the first).
NB: I found a trouble even when I'm trying to install packages from linux's terminal.

Comment: What error message do you get when installing packages? You should be able to install in your user-specific library because it's in ´.libPaths´. The second entry is probably where the system-wide installations are so you'll want to keep it.

Comment: I'm sure different university HPC have different rules regarding installation of packages, so my experience may not match yours. With my HPC, which uses a Bash shell in a linux environment (they're probably all linux, no?), after I log in with SSH on Xterm, I have to `load module R`. Then I start `R`. Then I `install.packages(<package>)`. That's it. I have to be in a user home directory, I can't be in a processing/job queue, there is no connection to internet there from which to install packages.

Comment: You can start R it sounds like. Can you load any base packages, like `MASS`? What does `sessionInfo()` return? Your HPC must have user documentation that explains basics, like where and how to install packages.

Comment: @Couldberry I tried but it didn't work. I got many errors but most of them are related to the admin (like I don't have the right to rewrite in the base). but I have loaded R inside Anaconda instead of the usual way like @John-Polo described exactly. After Anaconda Loaded I defined library of installation like `install.packages("package",lib="/home/..")` . so I think I solved the half of the problem. if I don't define `lib` during installation I got this error `installation of package ‘WGCNA’ had non-zero exit status` or `Packages "X" are not available for this version of R`.

Comment: What packages are you trying to install? Some packages rely on certain libraries that are supposed to be in the environment. For example `terra` relies on gdal-config and others in the environment I'm on, so I have to supply this argument: `install.packages("terra", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org', configure.args = c("--with-gdal-config=/usr/local/apps/gdal/gcc483-2.1.1/bin/gdal-config", "--with-proj-lib=/usr/local/apps/proj/gcc483-4.9.3/lib", "--with-proj=/usr/local/apps/proj/gcc483-4.9.3/bin/proj"))` Maybe it's the particular package you're trying to install. Honestly, I don't mind ...

Comment: ... helping, but a) I'm definitely no expert with this topic and b) this sounds like a question that the staff at your HPC should be able to answer. I noticed also that you referred to Anaconda. Using conda in my environment requires (and is generally permitted with a request to staff) a whole other directory and installing the packages that you want there and then activating the conda environment and a step or two more. I find it quite cumbersome. You wrote "@Couldberry" when you wanted Cloudberry. They probably did not get your message.